# Apache POI 3.11 Line Chart errorr

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for creating chart templates in Excel. I downloaded all of the Apache POI JAR files and imported them into project. I am successfully able to create ScatterChart but when I try to create LineChart, an errorr occurs which says: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method createLineChartData() is undefined for the type ChartDataFactory

    The method createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition) is undefined for the type ChartAxisFactory

Any suggestion?
**Edit 1 :** Problem got solved. I used Apache POI 3.10 Library. I think 3.11 is not complete. Will try using POI 3.12 once it gets stable release.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using older POI jars as well? See [this FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)

Comment: Nope.. I downloaded Apache POI 3.11 precisely.. even if you see the old POI src JARS at Java2S, you will not find the createLineChartData.

Comment: It [shows up in the javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/charts/ChartDataFactory.html#createLineChartData()) for me. You could try 3.12 beta 1, but I'm still worried you have older POI jars on your classpath...

Comment: It got solved. I used Apache POI 3.10 JARs and LineChart started executing without any error. I think the binaries provided in the POI 3.11 are incomplete.